# Как отследить в Windows 7, что и куда пишет драйвер при взаимодействии с устройством?

Tags: windows, отладка

На ноутбуке имеется несколько COM портов, но один из них глючный - Linux или MS DOS не могут прочитать его регистры по базовому адресу ввода-вывода 0x2f8 - всегда возвращается 0xff. Но в Windows 7 этот порт работает нормально.

Как отследить, что и в какие регистры пишет стандартный драйвер последовательного порта в Windows 7?
Ноутбук можно подключить через COM порт к другому компьютеру для отладки, сети на нём нет.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте посмотреть в диспетчере устройств:

[image: вкладка "ресурсы"]